# What tools and approaches can be used to improve application code quality?

Tags: code-quality

Teaching and education are clearly essential.

At a more practical and technical level, what tools and approaches can I use to improve code quality.  For example what tools exist for javascript under Node?

Code Quality in the sense that company and/or customers needs can be quickly addressed with the use of code that has the following characteristics:

- Secure
- Reliable
- Modular
- Scalable
- Well tested
- Performant
- Easy to read
- Easy to extend
- Easy to change
- Avoids known bugs
- Uses good practices
- Is consistently formatted
- Minimizes dependencies

and takes the least time and cost to change

Comment: Quality to whom? Quality is not a value-free attribute of something.

Comment: Thank you @JoãoFarias I've tried to add context for that.

Answer (score 1):

- Practise [Clean Code](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code) and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)
- Practise [Test-Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)
- Use a Static Code Analysis tool: For example I like to add [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) to the build-pipeline.

> SonarQube is an open-source platform developed by SonarSource for
>   continuous inspection of code quality to perform automatic reviews
>   with static analysis of code to detect bugs, code smells, and security
>   vulnerabilities on 20+ programming languages
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube

Answer (score 0):

### Tests are essential

- To ensure you have them, measure code coverage, for example <strike>Instanbul</strike> nyc.
- Test quality itself takes effort to maintain over time in order for tests to continue to *add* value

### Linting is essential

- Don't argue over syntax in Code Reviews, use tools such as ESlint with a robust configuration to prevent many potential bugs.  Robust configuration means use a LOT of rules to help you write quality code.  See below for list.

### Grading is important

- Use a tool that measures and grades your code, e.g. js-grader  Make sure grades don't drop

### Standardized formatting is helpful

- Use prettier or beautifier to standardize layout, improve readability and reduce variability
- Agree on standards through tool configuration over constant code review syntax discussions

### Automation of the above is essential!

The steps above MUST be incorporated into the development process as automatic procedures that make developers lives easier, not more burdensome.  For example, run linting and grading *before* tests, run tests automatically in the cloud in CI for all code commit pushes to remote *before* merging them into master, run tests in master *before* deploying to another environment, etc.  Automate code grading and consider a downgrade to be a failed test.  Make quality easy and instill pride in your developers.
Tools that can run various tasks are very helpful in these efforts.  For Javascript, **grunt** and **gulp** are major tools.  grunt is a little more established.  gulp runs faster due to using memory instead of file system.  Grunt uses one config file, gulp uses multiple files with javascript code to do configuration.  Using npm is almost de-facto and in 2020 npm can often be the only tool you'll need.  npm example config provided at the bottom.

---

Example `eslint.config` file that I am using:

```
rules:
  indent:
  - error
  - 2
  no-dupe-else-if: error
  no-dupe-keys: error
  no-duplicate-case: error
  no-unreachable: error
  prefer-const: error
  eqeqeq: error
  semi: error
  no-var: error
  no-fallthrough: error
  no-new: error
  no-redeclare: error
  vars-on-top: error
  default-param-last: error
  no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs: error
  no-tabs: error
  no-trailing-spaces: error
  no-irregular-whitespace: error
  no-unused-vars: error
  no-nested-ternary: error
  no-multiple-empty-lines: error
  no-extra-boolean-cast: warn
  no-extra-parens: warn
  default-case: warn
  no-else-return: warn
  no-eq-null: warn
  no-eval: warn
  no-loop-func: warn
  no-native-reassign: warn
  no-param-reassign: warn
  no-self-compare: warn
  accessor-pairs: warn
  block-scoped-var: warn
  no-throw-literal: warn
  prefer-regex-literals: warn
  camelcase: warn
  no-useless-rename: warn
  prefer-rest-params: warn
  prefer-template: warn
```

---

Example `package.json` file that I am using.
Note how scripts run linting, tests and code coverage every time.
Use

```
npm run coverage
```

to trigger all three scripts.

```
{
  "name": "binarySearchTree",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "eslint .",
    "test": "mocha **/*.spec.* --exclude node_modules/**/*.spec.js",
    "coverage": "nyc npm run test"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "nyc": "^15.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

Note the use of eslint-plugin-mocha, otherwise all the `describe`s and `it`s are unrecognized.

Comment: Other than JavaScript, you can add linting for almost anything: HTML, CSS, markdown, etc. I think it would be useful to add "how" to automate -- things like grunt, gulp, git hooks.